Why can we extend an operator to the von Neumann algebra?
Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete group, $C_r^* (\Gamma)$ its group $C^* $-algebra and $L(\Gamma)$ its group von Neumann algebra. I am trying to prove a result that is used in a paper I was reading.
Proposition There exists a normal $*$-embedding $\pi: L(\Gamma) \rightarrow L(\Gamma) \overline{\otimes} L(\Gamma)$ such that for all $x \in \Gamma$,
$$
\pi(\lambda_x) = \lambda_x \otimes \lambda_x.
$$
I have managed to do pretty much everything, using Fell's absorption principle and the definition of the spatial tensor product to get a map $C_r^* (\Gamma) \rightarrow C_r^* (\Gamma) \otimes C_r^* (\Gamma)$. However, I am having difficulties proving that I can extend this to $L(\Gamma) \rightarrow L(\Gamma) \overline{\otimes} L(\Gamma)$ in order to obtain the desired normal $*$-embedding, any help with this last step?

In this specific case, because the map obtained using Fell’s absorption principle is implemented by a unitary, and as $L(\Gamma)$ is the WOT closure of $C_r^\ast(\Gamma)$ and $L(\Gamma) \overline{\otimes} L(\Gamma)$ is the WOT closure of $C_r^\ast(\Gamma) \otimes C_r^\ast(\Gamma)$, you can directly obtain the desired extension that way. (That is, the map $C_r^\ast(\Gamma) = C_r^\ast(\Gamma) \otimes 1 \to C_r^\ast(\Gamma) \otimes C_r^\ast(\Gamma)$ is given by conjugation by a unitary $u$ on $\ell^2(\Gamma) \otimes \ell^2(\Gamma)$. The conjugation map by the same unitary then implements a normal $\ast$-embedding $L(\Gamma) = L(\Gamma) \otimes 1 \to L(\Gamma) \overline{\otimes} L(\Gamma)$.)
There is also a more general approach, applicable when dealing with tracial von Neumann algebras (which $L(\Gamma)$ is, as $\Gamma$ is discrete). Indeed, the following is a general fact:
Proposition: Let $M, N$ be tracial vNa’s, $A \subset M$ be a weakly dense $\ast$-subalgebra. Let $\pi: A \to N$ be a trace-preserving $\ast$-homomorphism. Then $\pi$ extends to a normal, trace-preserving, $\ast$-embedding $M \to N$.
Proof sketch: We have $L^2(\pi(A), \tau_N) \subset L^2(N, \tau_N)$ naturally. Since $\pi$ is trace-preserving and $A$ is weakly dense in $M$, we see that $L^2(M, \tau_M) = L^2(A, \tau_M) \simeq L^2(\pi(A), \tau_N)$, where the isomorphism is via $\pi$. On the other hand, $\pi(A)’’$ acts on $L^2(\pi(A)’’, \tau_N) = L^2(\pi(A), \tau_N)$. As $A$ is weakly dense in $M$ and $\pi(A)’’$, one may then check that the isomorphism of Hilbert spaces $L^2(M, \tau_M) \simeq L^2(\pi(A)’’, \tau_N)$ carries $M$ to $\pi(A)’’$. Since $\pi(A)’’ \subset N$, this gives the desired normal, trace-preserving, $\ast$-embedding $M \to N$. $\square$

Thank you a lot! I am working on some sorts of generalization of this result so the proposition you presented will be very useful. I did not understand why you mentioned that $\pi(A)''$ acts on $L^2(\pi(A),\tau_N)$, do you use to prove that $M$ is mapped to $\pi(A)''$?

@TomásPacheco $\pi(A)’’$ acts on $L^2(\pi(A)’’, \tau_N)$, which equals $L^2(\pi(A), \tau_N)$ as $A$ is weakly dense in $\pi(A)’’$. Similarly, $L^2(A, \tau_M)$ equals $L^2(M, \tau_M)$. The point is then, $\pi$ induces an isomorphism $L^2(A, \tau_M) \simeq L^2(\pi(A), \tau_N)$, which is also an isomorphism $L^2(M, \tau_M) \simeq L^2(\pi(A)’’, \tau_N)$. It is this spatial isomorphism that carries $M$ onto $\pi(A)’’$, which, composed with the embedding $\pi(A)’’ \to N$, gives the desired embedding $M \to N$.

Yes, I get it now, thank you!
